# What are the texts that describe buttons when you hover over them called?

Tags: interaction-design

I'm referring to these things:

[image: The thing I'm referring to]

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are called **tooltips**. See the [Material Design Spec](https://material.io/design/components/tooltips.html).

> Tooltips display informative text when users hover over, focus on, or tap an element.